# Cambiar imagen en JavaScript en evento onclick

Tags: javascript, img, src

Buenas estoy haciendo un desafio, sobre un encriptador de Mensajes, quiero lograr cambiar de imagen segun el estado del programa. Este conta de dos botones y la (1 imagen). Cuando oprimo el boton "Encriptar" se debe cambiar por la (2 imagen) eso lo logro hacer, mi problema es que no puedo cambiar a la tercera imagen, cuando oprimo el boton "desencriptar".
Por que utilice una funcion de cambiar el **src** de la imagen, de la 1 a la 2 y esta ultima no se como llamarla.
En el evento onclick llamo dos funciones, funcion encriptar(); funcion cambiarImagen1();

```
<img src="Img/buscar.png" id="ImgRight">



 function cambiarImagen1(){
   document.getElementById("ImgRight").src = "Img/encriptar.png";
    }
```

Comment: pasa un parámetro a la función para saber qué imagen poner, por ejemplo: cambiarImagen1(img) y luego if img==1 pones la 1, si es 2, la 2 y así... o directamente pasa la imagen como parámetro cambiarImagen1(img) y luego src = img

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, entiendo tu punto pero no me doy cuenta como aplicarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este codigo debería de funcionarte

**Html**

```
<img src="Img/buscar.png" id="ImgRight">
<input type="button" id="btnEncriptar" 
value="encriptar"/>

<input type="button" id="btnDesencriptar" 
    value="desencriptar"/>
```

**Javascript**

Al cargar la pagina realaizará esta funcion

```
    window.onload = inicializarEventos
    
    fuction.inicializarEventos(){
       document.getElementById("btnEncriptar").addEventListener("click", encriptar, false)
document.getElementById("btnDesencriptar").addEventListener("click", desencriptar, false)
    }


    function encriptar(){
        document.getElementById("ImgRight").src = "Img/encriptar.png";
      
    }

function desencriptar(){
document.getElementById("ImgRight").src = "ruta de la imagen";
}
```

Espero que te ayude‍

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tenemos el mismo resultado. Ahora el problema es si quiero ingresar una Tercer imagen, si nos centramos el la "funcion desencriptar", lo que hacemos es cambiar el src de la imagen, esta segunda imagen no tiene un "ID" para poder identificarla y cambiarla por la tercera

Comment: Esa imagen a la que le cambiamos el src seguira teniendo el mismo id que antes si no me equivoco no?

Comment: GRACIAS POR ESE DETALLE, si toma el mismo id. Le di otro enfoque y me funciono.

Comment: De nada ‍‍

Answer (score -1):

Podrías probar a recoger "imgRight" hacer un if dentro de la función. Si el src de la imagen es "Img/buscar.png" que la cambie por "Img/encriptar.png" y viceversa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, mi problema es como ingresar una tercer imagen.